# Wikimedia API: How to get page contents

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikimedia

I am trying to get the content of the wikimedia pages like these ones:

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Centralnotice-FR2015_translations-smallamount-error

https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:FundraisingBanners/SmallPrint-2017

I am working on something related to translations and banners but I'm stuck in this step.

I've been testing several of the endpoints in this API https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php with not succeed.

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are what you want:

```
https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=MediaWiki:Centralnotice-FR2015_translations-smallamount-error

https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=MediaWiki:FundraisingBanners/SmallPrint-2017
```

Let me know if you're struggling to extract the content from those.